# Pattern matching identical values

Tags: haskell, f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching, guard-clause

I just wondered whether it's possible to match against the same values for multiple times with the pattern matching facilities of functional programming languages (Haskell/F#/Caml).

Just think of the following example:

```
plus a a = 2 * a
plus a b = a + b
```

The first variant would be called when the function is invoked with two similar values (which would be stored in `a`).

A more useful application would be this (simplifying an AST).

```
simplify (Add a a) = Mult 2 a
```

But Haskell rejects these codes and warns me of *conflicting definitions for `a`* - I have to do explicit case/if-checks instead to find out whether the function got identical values. Is there any trick to indicate that a variable I want to match against will occur multiple times?

Comment: FWIW, Mathematica supports this.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is called a *nonlinear pattern*. There have been several threads on the haskell-cafe mailing list about this, not long ago. Here are two:

http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg59617.html

http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg62491.html

Bottom line: it's not impossible to implement, but was decided against for sake of simplicity.

By the way, you do not need `if` or `case` to work around this; the (slightly) cleaner way is to use a guard:

```
a `plus` b
  | a == b = 2*a
  | otherwise = a+b
```

Answer (score 15):

You can't have two parameters with the same name to indicate that they should be equal, but you can use [guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_%28computing%29) to distinguish cases like this:

```
plus a b
  | a == b    = 2 * a
  | otherwise = a + b
```

This is more flexible since it also works for more complicated conditions than simple equality.

Comment: Yes, I know guards but I tried to avoid any manual comparison.

Comment: Kinda shorthand for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480769/f-matching-with-two-values/501541#501541

Answer (score 0):

I have just looked up the mailing list threads given in Thomas's answer, and the very first reply in one of them makes good sense, and explains why such a "pattern" would not make much sense in general: *what if `a` is a function*?  (It is impossible in general to check it two functions are equal.)

Comment: Couldn't it just constrain `a` to be `Eq`?

Comment: @gdejohn, i suspect that the semantics would not be right. When applying a definition of the form `f x x = x`, one could reasonably expect IMO that the two submitted arguments are *the same value*, and not just "equal" in the sense of some typeclass (otherwise it is not even clear which of the two values of `x` should `f` return).

Answer (score -4):

I have implemented a new functional programming language that can handle non-linear patterns in Haskell.

https://github.com/egison/egison

In my language, your `plus` function in written as follow.

```
(define $plus
  (match-lambda [integer integer]
    {[[$a ,a] (* a 2)]
     [[$a $b] (+ a b)]}))
```